# Does anyone have a Core Data migration sample solution?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, xcode4

Does anyone have a sample application which makes use of mapping models in particular using the designer?

**Update:**  I am trying to understand how migration works using the designer - so I am looking for a project sample which has a few .xcdatamodels and one or two .xcmappingmodels so that I can learn and discover how to implement this in my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.html) which includes 5 sample applications.  See the section on

> Related sample code

See [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075) to learn about Core Data.

See [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html) for a detailed programming guide on model versioning as well as data migration.

Comment: Opened them myself using Xcode 4.  What problems are you having opening it?  What environment you using?

Comment: Failed to load project at '/Users/me/Documents/iOS code related/CoreRecipes/Hands-On Examples/Example 4 - Working with Core Data and Cocoa Bindings/CoreRecipesCocoaBindings-End/CoreRecipesCocoaBindings-End.xcode', incompatible project version.

Comment: Hrm, then this will work for you: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/IKImageBrowserViewWithCoreData/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007876.  It includes a very simple data model (1 entity) which I think will be helpful.

Comment: Apple's official examples are not particularly useful in terms of understanding the simplest way to make data model migrations work, reliably.